# Creating a .wav file in JS - "Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header"

Tags: javascript, web, header, wav, riff

I'm trying to record audio from the browser's microphone, and save it as a .wav file (to be sent to an API)

I've got the binary blocks of what I'm after, and I can convert it to a .wav file that plays in VLC (and also in the browser)

```
let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
```

But when I try to send it to the http://www.beyondverbal.com/api/, I receive

```
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"status\":\"failure\",\"reason\":\"Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header\"}","status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request"}
```

Essentially the question is, how can I add the RIFF header I need, or am I going about this completely all wrong?

Thanks

Comment: @JaromandaX - that's from me just copy and pasting it - amended it now :) Thanks

Comment: Hi, did you managed how resolved it? I've got the same problem.